# mvc3 MultiLine EditFor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a view that is tightly bound to a model. The model has a string property[statement] and im using the property to capture user data. In the view i want the [statement] to be a multiline EditorFor field. In my model I applied a attribute/data annotation to property and the attribute being [DataType(DataType.MultiLineText)] but it does not seem to be working?
Please help

```
    @item.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)
    @item.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
    @item.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
    @item.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
    @item.EditorFor(m => m.statement)
    <span id="admin">
    @item.CheckboxFor(m => m.IsAdmin)
    </span>
```

Comment: code please and make sure you generate the view after you placed the datatype attribute

Comment: When you say generate, what do you mean? I made the changes to the model. Isnt the view surpose to be generated when i debug or run the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`TextAreaFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703551.aspx) not `EditorFor`:

```
@item.TextAreaFor(m => m.MyField)
```

Comment: No problems :) glad I could help!